# Vis.js Timeline with verticalScroll at the right side

Tags: javascript, timeline, vis.js

I'm using the Vis.js timeline library with the option `verticalScroll: true`. I'm following this example: https://visjs.github.io/vis-timeline/examples/timeline/other/verticalScroll.html

```
  ...
  var options = {
    stack: true,
    verticalScroll: true,
    zoomKey: 'ctrlKey',
    maxHeight: 200,
    start: new Date(),
    end: new Date(1000*60*60*24 + (new Date()).valueOf()),
  };

  // create a Timeline
  var container1 = document.getElementById('mytimeline1');
  timeline1 = new vis.Timeline(container1, items, groups, options);
```

I need to put the scroll bar at the right side. Is it possible?
Is there any configuration option to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `maxHeight` property in the options, you will then see the scroll bar on the right side.

Comment: But I need the `maxHeight`. Removing the `maxHeight` the parent element or the whole page will have the scroll bar, not only the timeline.